# $this->pagination->create_links(); returning blank string

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

```
<?php
    class Books extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
  }

  function index() {
    // load pagination class
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'books/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = 2;
    $config['per_page'] = '5';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<p>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    echo $this->pagination->create_links();

  }
    }
?>
```

The create_links(); function seems to not be working. I don't get any errors, but it just returns a blank string. I've tried both http://blip.tv/nettuts/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-2690301 and http://godbit.com/article/pagination-with-code-igniter tutorials.

I'm aware the documentation says http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html `The create_links() function returns an empty string when there is no pagination to show.` but so how do I fix that?
Thanks you!

> Blockquote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think because you don't have any data for pagination. This is a working example:

```
    $this->load->model('books_model', 'books');

    $offset = $this->uri->segment(n);
    $per_page = 5;
    $total = $this->books->total();
    $data['result'] = $this->books->get_all($per_page, $offset);

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'books/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $total;
    $config['per_page'] = $per_page;

    $this->load->vars($data); // !!!
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: If you don't have a model, you can try to paginate an array:
$data = array('page1', 'page2') etc..

Comment: Yeah, the tutorials never mentioned having to load the $data as vars $this->load->vars($data). I think they might be slightly out-dated.